# Is this a genuine Facebook link?

Tags: facebook, phishing

> http://www.facebook.com/confirmemail.php?e=user%40email_address_removed_for_security_reasons.com&c=175274284&report=1

I got this in an email and wanted to know if it is a genuine Facebook link, or is someone trying to fake it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important thing is the *domain* of the link. When you hover on that link, if the URL that shows up (usually at the bottom left of the browser window) starts with http://facebook.com or https://facebook.com, then it is safe no matter what follows the site root.

That being said, the link you gave opens a Facebook page to **Report Mistaken Email**. It says:

> If you are receiving notifications at
>   user@email_address_removed_for_security_reasons.com
>   for a Facebook account that you do not
>   own, please report this account for
>   potential abuse.

and there is a button named "Report Abuse" below the message.

Answer (score 1):

If I was you I wouldnt trust it instead id go to facebook its self login and see if I had any notifications etc as it should display it on the site if its offical.